# Decrease the number of needed if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this code using Python:

```
a = ["Porsche", "Google", "Facebook", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Twitter"]

if "Porsche" in a:
    pass
if "Google" in a:
    pass
if "Facebook" in a:
    pass 
if "Mercedes" in a:
    pass
if "Audi" in a:
    pass
if "Twitter" in a:
    pass
```

But, with this code, I have no idea how I can decrease the number of needed `if` statements. Is there a better way using Python to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `if` statements?

Comment: It depends on what will go in your `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your question right. You want less if-Statements? If that's what you want: It depends on what you're doing in the if-Statements. If you do similar thing, that's no problem. Then you could use something like:

```
if 'Porsche' in a or 'Google' in a:
    pass
```

If you're doing different things, you need all of those if statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want less if statements, you could use a for loop running through a list.

Example:

```
a = ["Porsche", "Google", "Facebook", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Twitter"]

# you can change the values to whatever you want
b = ["Porsche", "Google", "Facebook", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Twitter"]


for i in range(len(a)):
    if b[i] in a:
        pass
```

An added benefit is that it isn't hard coded, so you can change it to anything you want, and add more programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `pass` statements all represent the same code, the conditions can be combined using `or`:

```
if ("Porsche" in a) or ("Google" in a) or ("Facebook" in a) or ("Mercedes" in a) or ("Audi" in a) or ("Twitter" in a):
    pass
```

(The parentheses are all optional, but they make the statement much easier to read.)

Simplifying further using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
if any((x in a) for x in ("Porsche", "Google", "Facebook", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Twitter")):
    pass
```

(As before, the parentheses around `(x in a)` are optional but help readability. The other parentheses are required.)

Comment: One alternative can be `if len(set(things).intersection(a)) > 0: # do something`. This is not the best, just one alternative.

Comment: @Poojan That seems like an unnecessarily complicated way of going about it, though.

Comment: @Poojan you could further reduce it down to `if set(things).intersection(a): # do something`, but you lose all of your readability that's quite well provided by `thing in collection`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check if something is a member of the list you can use `in` to reduce the number of `if` statements:

```
companies_list = ["Porsche", "Google", "Facebook", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Twitter"]
count = 0
if "Apple" in companies_list: # O(n)
   count += 1
print(count)
```

However using `in` on a list is `O(n)` i.e. it has to check against every item in the list which is not good if you have a lot of items.

Therefore consider using a set rather than a list, since searching in a set has `O(1)` look up time:

```
companies_set = {"Porsche", "Google", "Facebook", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Twitter"}
count = 0
if "Apple" in companies_set: # O(1)
   count += 1
print(count)
```

**Output:**

```
0
```